# Cant access custom value in request NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to store some random value in my request. Like this:

```
req.name = "Mark"
```

The problem is i can only access it in the controller i set it. When I

```
console.log(req.name)
```

in another controller i get **undefined.**

My code is here:

```
export const getCaptcha = async (req, res, next) => {
    const captcha = await svgCaptcha.createMathExpr({
        size: 5,
        noise: 3,
        color: true,
        background: '#08af96'
    })

    req.captcha = captcha.text
    res.status(200).send(captcha.data)
}

export const checkCaptcha = (req, res, next) => {
    const { result } = req.body
    console.log(req.captcha)
    // if (result !== req.captcha) {
    //  throw new Error('Invalid captcha!')
    // }

    // res.status(200).json({
    //  message: 'Success'
    // })
}
```

Route component:

```
import express from 'express'
import { getCaptcha, checkCaptcha } from '../controllers/captcha'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/captcha', getCaptcha)
router.post('/captcha', checkCaptcha)

export default router
```

App.js

```
import captchaRoutes from './routes/captcha'    
app.use(captchaRoutes)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show where you're using both middlewares.

Comment: In my captcha routes file. I have get route for getCaptcha and post route for checkCaptcha. And i used it in my app.js with app.use(captchaRoutes)

Comment: Show that code, otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I edited my question, u can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Since getCaptcha and checkCaptcha are two different middlewares used in two difference endpoints req object is not shared between your requests. So if you set some property in req during specific request you will never get this very value from another request because req object will be completely new.

So what you need is to have a different place where you store your captcha information.

For instance it could be redis.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to keep my captcha result only for that request ?

Comment: You can check out this package: https://github.com/lazarofl/svg-captcha-express. It uses express-session which use memory-storage by default as your sessions storage, so be careful in your production environment.